# if and else in Convolution function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, if-statement, convolution

I have a problem with use `if` and `else` statement in convolution function.

this code return error:

> use any() or all()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def name(y):
  if y<300 :
      print("if")
      fun2=y-6
      return fun2
  else:
      fun2=6-y
      print("else")
      return fun2

y=np.arange(1,1000,1) 
x=np.arange(1,1000,1)
fun1=np.sin(x)
con=np.convolve(fun1,name(y))
plt.plot(con)
plt.show()
```

how to can i use condition in convolve?

I hope you always good luck.
thanks.

Comment: Why do you need both? if `np.all` is `True` than `np.any` is `True` and if `np.any` is good enough  `np.all` is redundant.

Comment: Is `if all(y_i<300 for y_i in y):` what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` function is called with a numpy array as the parameter.  "Is the array less than 300?" isn't meaningful.  Are all the items less than 300, `np.all`? Are any of them less than 300, `np.any`?
My guess is that you want something like:

```
def name( y ):
    sign = 1 - 2*(y>300)
    return sign * (y-6)

y = np.arange( 290, 310 )
name( y )

# array([ 284,  285,  286,  287,  288,  289,  290,  291,  292,  293,  294,
#        -295, -296, -297, -298, -299, -300, -301, -302, -303])
```

This uses the boolean result for each item in the array to perform arithmetic and is one way of allowing different treatments for different elements in an array.